# Star - look for the character * in a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find the following text in my string : `'***'`
the thing is that the C# Regex mechanism doesnt allow me to do the following:

```
new Regex("***", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

due to

> ArgumentException: "parsing "***" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."

obviously it thinks that my stars represents regular expressions,
is there a way to tell the Regex mechanism to treat stars as just stars and nothing else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to **escape** the star with a backslash: `@"\*"`

Answer (score 19):

***`*`*** in `Regex` means:

> Matches the previous element zero or more times.

so that, you need to use `\*` or `[*]` instead.

explain:

> ***`\`***
>
> When followed by a character that is not recognized as an escaped character in this and other tables in this topic, matches that character. For example, `\*` is the same as `\x2A`.
>
> ***`[ character_group ]`***
>
> Matches any single character in `character_group`.